# Diagonal movement

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to implement an enemy that chases the player, but when the enemy moves diagonally, it appears to move slower than when it moves on a single axis and I'm not sure why. Here's my code for the enemy:

```
import pygame
import constants
import math
from Character import Player

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, filename, x, y):

        super().__init__()    

        self.image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(constants.BLACK)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x

        self.speedx = -3
        self.speedy = -3

        self.health = 100

    def update(self, player):

        dx = self.rect.x - player.rect.x
        dy = self.rect.y - player.rect.y

        dist = math.hypot(dx, dy)

        dx = dx / dist
        dy = dy / dist

        self.rect.x += dx * self.speedx
        self.rect.y += dy * self.speedy




* in the main loop *

current_room.enemy_sprites.update(player)
```

Let me know if any more code is necessary, but I don't think there would be as none of my other code affects the enemy movement. Any help at all would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

When you move horizontally or vertically your speed is `-3`, when you move diagonally, your speed becomes `-3 / 1.41` (let's consider `dx == dy`), and because of the rounding it becomes just `2`, which is about 1.5 times slower.

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense, how would I implement that into my coding though? I've tried a few if statements but nothing quite seems to let me modify the speed to 3 * 1.41 when moving diagonally